# @RestController accepting unwanted tags also

Tags: spring, rest, web-services, spring-boot

I created a spring REST web service using spring boot. It accepts XML in requestbody. The problem is, it accepting unwanted tags also and giving the results, which I want to restrict and notify user about this.
How can i validate the request body (xml) against xsd before it reaches controller or by any other way. Please suggest.

Controller:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/webservice/{text}", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE })
    public ServiceResult processRequest(@PathVariable("text") String text,
            @RequestBody Request Request) {
```

Beans:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Request")
@XmlType(propOrder = {"requestHeader", "requestBody"})
public class Request implements Serializable {

    private RequestHeader requestHeader;
    private RequestBody requestBody;

    @XmlElement(name="RequestHeader")
    public RequestHeader getRequestHeader() {
        return requestHeader;
    }

    public void setRequestHeader(RequestHeader requestHeader) {
        this.requestHeader = requestHeader;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="RequestBody")
    public RequestBody getRequestBody() {
        return requestBody;
    }

    public void setRequestBody(RequestBody requestBody) {
        this.requestBody = requestBody;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share what have you done so far?

Comment: add some code to understand

Comment: added, Please check

Comment: Are you using Jackson for deserealizing?

Comment: @lopushen yes i am using Jackson.

Comment: @lopushen Thanks for your guidance. You guided me to the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you might want to fail on unwanted tags: https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES 
Also, if you can make use of bean validation to validate the values. However, this validation has nothing to do with xsd

Answer (score 0):

Adding the below property to application.properties files solved my problem.

spring.jackson.deserialization.fail-on-unknown-properties=true